# JavaScript code does not work after ReactDOM used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used react.js in my new project and found that javascript didn't work when I used ReactDOM to render class extended from React.Component

When script which fire alert() method is used as last it does not works. 
When I change order of scripts, they work.

```
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="hello"><div>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script>
class HelloReact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello world 1!"));
  }
} 

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloReact, null), document.getElementById("hello"));
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello, world 2!"), document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
<script>alert("Hello");</script>
```

I would know is it normal (and I should not use javascript code after scripts with react code) or there is a bug in react library?

I was checking in Dev Tools and wasn't see any errors. I added files to github [ https://github.com/darekjk/reactjs_examples/tree/master/react-js-problem-20181231 ]  to be sure I didn't make any error in copy/paste.

Comment: Open the web inspector in chrome and look at the javascript error

Comment: I pushed code to github. Please note that when I comment line:
    //ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloReact, null), document.getElementById("hello")); 
code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, I spotted the actual error here, it's a funny one.

### Take a look at this line: `<div id="hello"><div>`.

You meant to write `<div id="hello"></div>` but missed the slash.

This means that all your tags after that line are **inside** the *hello* div (and the other unnamed div that was supposed to be a closing tag). You can check it in the *Elements* view of *Chrome Dev Tools*.

[image: Dom structure]

This means that when ReactDOM renders your class into the hello div, **it overwrites everything**, because **everything is inside the *hello* div**, including itself and that other script tag. In the screenshot above you can see that all the script tags are missing.

Comment: Thanks. :) I didn't work too much with Chrome Dev Tols and didn't know that it will not analyze html to check if all closing tags exists. I analyzed all divs in Dev Tools where all was closed :)

Comment: The trick is that Dev Tools will always show a valid HTML. Chrome tries to fix your errors and produce a valid DOM Tree, and the tools then display the DOM Tree to you not the original source. 
To check for errors use another tool, such as the good old W3C Validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Yes, I know w3c validator, but tried to use something offline. I started to use tidy. It works fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you see javascript simply not executing, you 99% **have a javascript error occuring before**.

Interestingly your code does run on both my local machine and JsFiddle.

But if it still has problems in your specific scenario, start with opening up Chrome Dev Tools (F12) and look at the Console for any JavaScript errors.

[image]

Comment: I know, but the code is very simple and I don't see any error in debugger. Please see full code on github.